# R package mstate: bug in contributed program transMat()

Tags: r, package

I have come across a bug in the contributed function transMat() in the mstate package.  I am working with a four state problem:

1. State 1:  A patient gets an islet transplant
2. State 2:  The patient may become insulin independent
3. State 3:  A patient that became insulin loses insulin independent but still retains some insulin output. Once in this state, it is impossible to return to the insulin independent state (within the context of my problem.)
4. State 4:  A patient may go from any of the above three states above to complete rejection of the transplant.

So the possible transitions are:

From State 1:  to state 2 or state 4.  (You can't have loss of
insulin independence unless you have achieved it.)
2. From State 2:  to  state 3 or 4.
3. From State 3:  only to state 4.
4. State 4 is an "absorbing state."  There are no further possible transitions (again, within the context of my analysis).

This can be programmed as follows:

> ```
> tmat4a <- matrix(NA, 4,4)
> tmat4a[1, c(2, 4)] <- c(1, 3)
> tmat4a[2, c(3, 4)] <- c(3, 4)
> tmat4a[3, 4] <- 4
> dimnames(tmat4a) <- list(from = c('Tx', 'II', 'failII', 'fail'), to = c('Tx', 'II', 'failII', 'fail'))
> > tmat4a
>         to
> from     Tx II failII fail
>   Tx     NA  1     NA    3
>   II     NA NA      3    4
>   failII NA NA     NA    4
>   fail   NA NA     NA   NA
> ```

The following code is supposed to give the same answer:

```
tmat4 <- transMat(x = list(c(2, 4), c(3, 4), c(4), c()), 
                  names = c('Tx', 'II', 'failII', 'fail'))
```

Unfortunately, it gives the wrong matrix:

```
> tmat4
        to
from     Tx II failII fail
  Tx     NA  1     NA    2
  II     NA NA      3    4
  failII NA NA     NA    5
  fail   NA NA     NA   NA
```

Note the 5, rather than 4 in [3,4].  The possible transitions are not always sequential.  Sometimes two prior levels can transition to the same subsequent state.
Larry Hunsicker

Comment: Looking at the documentation examples for `transMat`, this seems to be the desired behaviour. I'm no expert in this subject, it seems to me that all the possible transitions are numbered with a unique number

Comment: My bad.  It turns out that it makes no difference what number one puts in the columns of the matrix.  All that matters is that there is a  value there.  It can even be a character.  The next function paths() assigns the possible paths in order irrespective of the values (so long as they are not NA).